# google sheets conditional formatting across sheets [range trouble]

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I need to format a range of cells in `Sheet1` according to values in `Sheet2`. Explicitly, Cell `Sheet1!B2` must be formatting according to value in `Sheet2!B2`, `Sheet1!C10` according to `Sheet2!C10` and so on...

This Conditional formatting formula works just fine:

- RANGE: `Sheet1!B2:B`
- FORMULA: `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!B2:B")>100 (works fine, cell-by-cell)`

But when I expand the range to something like the below, it formats nothing anywhere... It doesn't work:

- RANGE: `Sheet1!B2:C`
- FORMULA: `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!B2:C")>100 (does nothing in either column B or C)`

When I try the below it formats "by line", `Sheet1!B2:C2`, `Sheet1!B10:C10`, etc for instance:

- RANGE: `Sheet1!B2:C`
- FORMULA: `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!B2:B")>100`

I need formatting "by cell", for example `Sheet1!B2`, `Sheet1!C10`, and so on.

Comment: MORE INFO: When I try RANGE: Sheet1!B2:C and FORMULA: =INDIRECT("Sheet2!B2")>100, dows NOT work either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly temperamental but please try clearing formatting from and selecting ColumnsA:F (or to suit, but whole columns for simplicity) and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... **Custom formula is** and:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&address(row(),column()))>100
```

Then select formatting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Comment: That's the one and only in the web perfect solution for cross-sheets cell-by-cell conditional formating in Google Sheets. Congrats! Thanks so much!